# Delete all files in directories tomcat_*/temp on each application restart

Tags: bash, find, rm, exec

We do have an operation script to stop, restart and start tomcat services. I am asked to make changes in the operation script so when starting tomcat with operation_script.sh, All files in directories tomcat_*/temp should be deleted on each application start.

Script is long so I will do snippet.

```
## service tomcat
if [[ ${service} == "tomcat" ]]; then

  case ${operation} in 
    stop) # stop tomcat java processes
    
      $DIR/command_bsiadmin.sh "
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl stop bsicrm_${port_ui}.service;
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl stop bsicrm_${port_be}.service;
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl stop bsicrm_${port_se}.service; " "$1"
      tomcat_status
      ;;
    
    start) # start tomcat java processes  

      $DIR/command_bsiadmin.sh "
      find /opt/tsi/app/tomcat_*/temp/* -exec rm -rf {} + \; 2>/dev/null; # Here I apply my solution 
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start bsicrm_${port_se}.service;  
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start bsicrm_${port_be}.service;
      sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start bsicrm_${port_ui}.service;
```

After the tomcats started, None of temp files were deleted. Tested several times but I have no idea where I am doing wrong. Shouldn't `find -exec rm` command delete all files in directories tomcat_*/temp??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The command is passed to your custom script `command_bsiadmin.sh`. Without understanding what that does it's not possible to explain why your command doesn't work

Comment: I think, that scripts contains admin rights and Full path of operation script.

Comment: I suggest you isolate your code (essentially the `find` command) into a test script that you can run and debug in a non-critical directory.  That way you won't have to jack your Tomcat service around while you're debugging code that doesn't do what you want and could potentially go sideways on you. Once you've figured out the correct syntax to remove the files you want to remove, then you can proceed to the second step of how to integrate that change into your service script.

Comment: It seems strange that you need to use `sudo` when your `service` script is already running as root. Does your custom script `command_bsiadmin.sh` change ownership to something else that then needs to become root again? If so, that could explain why your `find`/`rm` code fails